# SUM(Table) not working when using SqlCommand

Tags: c#, sql-server

When I run the code the result will be of 'Type' instead of the SUM of Name.
Tried also do the SUM inside the Reader[("Types")] and it displays SUM(Types). It should display the amount of that particular name

Code inside c#:

```
public void DisplayName()
{
        try
        {
            string Connection = @"Data Source=local;Initial Catalog=Project;Integrated Security=True";
            SqlConnection Connect = new SqlConnection(Connection);

            string Name;

            Console.WriteLine("\nShowing Name\n");

            Console.WriteLine("Enter name type: \n");
            country = Console.ReadLine();

            ConnectingDatabase.Open();

            string Query = "SELECT SUM(Types) FROM PersonName WHERE Name = @Name";

            SqlCommand Commands = new SqlCommand(Query, ConnectingDatabase, ConnectingDatabase.BeginTransaction());

            Commands.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Name", country));

            SqlDataReader Reader = ParaComm.ExecuteReader();

            if (Reader.Read())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Your name is " + name + " with sum of {0}\n", Reader[("Types")]);
            }

            Reader.Close();
            ParaComm.Transaction.Commit();
            Connect.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
}
```

Comment: Use `COUNT(*)`. `SUM` is to add numbers.

Comment: I tried it COUNT(Types) but still it doesnt work @OlivierJacot-Descombes

Comment: Thanks @Renat it worked!!!

Comment: You could give some example input together with the expected output.

Comment: I see no answer or comment from Renat.

Comment: He removed it..@Amy

Comment: The answer was 'Console.WriteLine("Your name is " + name + " with sum of 
     {0}\n", Reader[0]);'

Comment: In the future when you run into trouble, [use the debugger](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/) to look at what `Reader` contains.

Comment: Good point, I try my best @DourHighArch

Comment: Try Adding **"Group By"**. Maybe this help

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Group By` when use aggregeate function in sql. Try this Sql-Command

```
 string Query = "SELECT SUM(Types) FROM main.Stats Group by column_name WHERE 
 Name = @Name";
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, but the problem has been solved!

Comment: You don't need a GROUP BY if you are not grouping on any column

Answer (score 0):

As you learned, you can always reference a column by the column number.  i.e `0` in this case.

However, the easiest way to deal with this moving forward, and avoid issues with changes to a query that cause column numbers to change, is to provide an alias for the column.

If you add an alias to your query, changing it to
`SELECT SUM(Types) as TypeSum FROM PersonName WHERE Name = @Name` you should find that you can access the value using `Reader["TypeSum"]` syntax.